# Add a <img src=*****><br> at the end of this regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Hello how can I add a `<img src=*****><br>` at the end of every match but without array because I will encode the results?

```
preg_match_all('!http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui', $content, $filtered);
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something: `implode('<br>', $filtered)` and then add one more at the end...

Comment: Maybe you should use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead so you can replace your matches with your formated string, just as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(preg_match_all('#http://[\S]+(?:jpe?g|png|gif)#is', $html, $matches)){
$i = 0;
foreach($matches[0] as $value){
    if(in_array($i, array(0, 3))) continue;
    $img .= '<img src="'.$value.'"><br>';
    $i++;
    }
}

echo $img;
```

Output (removed domain name by hand)

```
<img src="http://galerije/ford%20focus/qy974l.jpg"><br><img src="http://galerije/ford%20focus/m8zhh0.jpg"><br><img src="http://galerije/ford%20focus/ifpixx.jpg"><br><img src="http://galerije/ford%20focus/1zvzof8.jpg"><br><img src="http://galerije/ford%20focus/ir8cqv.jpg"><br><img src="http://galerije/ford%20focus/9vjtrd.jpg"><br><img src="http://galerije/ford%20focus/2m29p4j.jpg"><br><img src="http://galerije/ford%20focus/znm0yt.jpg"><br><img src="http://galerije/ford%20focus/2ln8l7t.jpg"><br><img src="http://galerije/ford%20focus/mta0ap.jpg"><br>
```

Comment: Thanks Webarto! How can I ignore the 1st and 4rth match ?

Comment: @Punkis I have updated answer, you have to unset 0 and 3, try it.

Comment: Webarto I think it doesnt work... I get all the resultw without unset, and a blank page with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the results and store them in an array:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = $filtered[0] . "<br/>";
```

Comment: What structures are you allowed to use?

Comment: Hi Cristina. I updated my entire question. The reason why I need to avoid arrays is because I want to encode the matches.

Comment: It would be great if I had only the regex. like this `/src=["\'](.*)+["\']/` that writes src=

Comment: You need whatever images you find to be put under a <img src=image_found> </br>?